# Is it safe to mix IO styles on a file with Posix file control (fcntl) and std::filebuf in C++?

Tags: c++, ostream, fcntl

I'm trying to chase down an intermittent SEG FAULT on an ostream insert and I've come across code that looks something like this:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
 ...
std::filebuf logBuf;
std::ostream fout;

int logFD = open(myfile, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_APPEND, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
logBuf.open(myFile, ios::out|ios::app);
fout.rdbuf(&logBuf);
```

This doesn't feel right, but I can't find anything that says whether it is safe to mix IO styles on a file like this.

Does this need a rewrite or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: It's not impossible, but I wouldn't normally expect mixing I/O styles to cause a segfault.   You may get I/O problems (e.g. output lost, out of sequence, etc) on mixing I/O styles due to different styles using different buffering, so operations would not always align.    However, there are many ways that a segfault can occur (many ways of undefined behaviour affecting things until, eventually, the OS detects your program doing something it shouldn't and kills it [a segfault is a visible manifestation of a kill signal from the OS].

Comment: Thanks, @Peter.  I thought I might be onto something but it looks like I was in fact barking up the wrong tree.